# How to set the selected value for a drop down list based on another drop down list?

Tags: javascript

If I select x value in the first drop down list, then Y value would be selected on the second drop down list.

Answer (score 3):

If you wan it in jQuery then;

```
$("#yourFirstSelectId").change(function() {
   var firstSelected = $(this).val();
   $("#yourSecondSelectId option:selected").val(firstSelected);
});
```

Comment: He didn't tag it as jquery but his question was also not very clear. So good answer. :)

Comment: +1 but yea, he didn't tag it as jquery... oh well, had to cast one more vote and you gave a "javascript" answer! (:

Comment: @sudhir can you please give an example using the above code..I'm trying to do the same thing but my code is not working..